# Include a rotation Axis to Turtlebot

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to modify the turtlebot model to add a rotation axis to the kinect camera to move it like a type of neck or something like that but I don't know exactly if I need to change the type of the joint of the kinect camera on turtlebot_description files

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280715/include-a-rotation-axis-to-turtlebot/) by [Dcannt](https://answers.ros.org/users/33410/dcannt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-02-14**:
Sorry it was tagged as hydro and I closed it all hydro tagged questions. Reopening.

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2018-02-14**:
No worries Tully. I thought that this was a very good question to answer because it is very common to decide to add a rotating joint here or there in the robot, but it is not trivial how to do that in the simulation so the joint can be controlled properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The question was closed while I was preparing a complete answer. Basically, what you need is to change the type of joint that ties the Kinect to the Turtlebot structure from `fixed` to `continuous`. Then you need to add the controller for the joint. Video showing how to: https://youtu.be/Y5K4gF2teIA

---

Originally posted by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) with karma: 874 on 2018-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0